# Recode range multiple columns in r

Tags: r, multiple-columns, flags, recode

I cannot find an answer to this specific question. I would like to recode multiple character columns into numeric columns. (It is a hundred columns) But:

- columns will not always be in the same order (I recode
  the refreshed data every month).
- columns are separated by columns that I do not wish to recode.
- dataset does not always include the same columns.

So, I do not think I can  use a range of column indexes. However, the columns I wish to recode start with the same column name prefix.  I would like to recode any "Yes" to 1, "No" to 0, and blanks to NA.

I could do this manually one column at a time with the  below code:

```
    #Recode columns one at a time

    library(car)
    #skip ID column
    #Skip Date column
    df$Q1<-as.numeric(as.character(recode(df$Q1,"NA=NA; 'No'=0; 'Yes'=1; ''=NA")))
    df$Q2<-as.numeric(as.character(recode(df$Q2,"NA=NA; 'No'=0; 'Yes'=1; ''=NA")))
    #skip Q2.Explanation column
    #do the above for a hundred more columns...
```

But I would like to recode a hundred, specific columns at the same time. Also these columns are separated by columns I do not wish to recode.

My data is below. Not sure what is dput:

```
    ID<-c(01,02,03,04,05)
    Q1<-c("Yes", NA,"", "No",NA)
    Q1.Explanation<-c (NA, NA,"","Respondent did not get the correct answer", NA)
    Q2<-c("No","Yes","Yes","", NA)
    Q2.Explanation <-c("The right answer was not proven", NA, NA, NA, NA)
    Q3<-c("", NA, "Yes", NA, NA)
    Mydata<-as.data.frame(cbind(ID,Q1,Q1.Explanation, Q2, Q2.Explanation,Q3))
```

Comment: You can use `grepl()` function combined with the `prefix` to find out the columns that you want to recode and then loop through the columns for recoding. If you want a more specific answer, pls provide a example of your data.frame by pasting the `dput` of your data.

Comment: Is the recode logic always the same for all columns you want to recode (in other word: Does the translation always use the same mapping logic)?

Comment: Yes, the recode logic is always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the columns you want to change always have the same names, just different locations in the table, then you can use regex on the column names to subset, then change the values in the columns with `apply()`.

```
your_data[, grep("Q", colnames(your_data))] <- as.data.frame(apply(your_data[, grep("Q", colnames(your_data))], 
                               2, 
                               function(x) recode(x, "NA = NA; 'No' = 0; 'Yes' = 1; '' = NA")))
```

This should recode all of your columns that begin with "Q" regardless of their location any given month.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am new to R. Am I supposed to replace the part of your code that says 'function(x) recode(x)?' I get an error on that part.

Comment: I think you have to replace "your_data" with the name of your data.frame variable adjust the column name part ("Q") with the substring the filters your column names (whose values shall be recoded)

Comment: If you share some of your data using `dput()` and share the error, I might be able to help with it.  Otherwise, I can only go off of what you have posted.

Comment: The code worked  to recode all the columns after I deleted the very last parenthesis. The error is gone. But, the dataset only kept the columns with a "Q" in them... The error that is now gone had been: Error: unexpected ')' in:
"                                   2, 
                                   function(x) recode(x, "NA = NA; 'No' = 0; 'Yes' = 1; '' = NA"))))"

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - my bad.  Try `dput(Mydata)`, to see how that works.  I'll update the answer to bind the updated columns to the original frame.

Comment: But also, how to make the recoded columns numeric instead of factor level?

Comment: You never mentioned anything about that in your question... I'll try to help but if you have more questions you should google around or post another one on SO.  To change your recoded columns to numeric, try `updated_data[, grep("Q", colnames(updated_data)] <- as.numeric(updated_data[, grep("Q", colnames(updated_data)])`, though you might have some issues with the NAs.

Comment: Thanks, but also, I did mention numeric in my question...It is the first part of the question...

Comment: Sorry, my bad (again).  If the answer works for you, please mark it as answered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111567/discussion-between-smith-and-raphael-k).

Comment: @MarySmith Mary, I think you should at least upvote the answer of Raphael (and mark his answer as  "accepted") to reward his great work :-)

Answer (score 1):

For `data.table` fans I have another solution that also has the advantage of using `factors` instead of numeric integers for the recoding so that
**the meaning of the numeric values is still displayed correctly** (improving the readability of your data):

```
library(data.table)

ID<-c(01,02,03,04,05)
Q1<-c("Yes", NA,"", "No",NA)
Q1.Explanation<-c (NA, NA,"","Respondent did not get the correct answer", NA)
Q2<-c("No","Yes","Yes","", NA)
Q2.Explanation <-c("The right answer was not proven", NA, NA, NA, NA)
Q3<-c("", NA, "Yes", NA, NA)
Mydata<-as.data.frame(cbind(ID,Q1,Q1.Explanation, Q2, Q2.Explanation,Q3))

Mydata

# The solution starts here... ----------------------------------------------

setDT(Mydata)     # convert data.frame into data.table

# the regular expression selects all column names starting with a "Q" followed by digits until the end
affected.cols <- colnames(Mydata)[grep("^Q\\d+$", colnames(Mydata))]

# convert the columns to factors; trailing square brackets are only added to print the output
Mydata[, (affected.cols) := lapply(affected.cols, function(x) { .SD[, factor(get(x), c("No", "Yes")) ] })] []

str(Mydata)           # Columns are encoded as factors ("enumerated types") now, which is an integer internally that has a string label

# Proof: 1 = "No", 2 = "Yes"; the "excluded" parameter of "factor()" caused all other values (mainly empty strings) to be translated into NAs
as.numeric(Mydata$Q1)
```

Which results in:

```
> as.numeric(Mydata$Q1)
[1]  2 NA NA  1 NA


> Mydata
   ID  Q1                            Q1.Explanation  Q2                  Q2.Explanation  Q3
1:  1 Yes                                        NA  No The right answer was not proven  NA
2:  2  NA                                        NA Yes                              NA  NA
3:  3  NA                                           Yes                              NA Yes
4:  4  No Respondent did not get the correct answer  NA                              NA  NA
5:  5  NA                                        NA  NA                              NA  NA
```

The correct translation to the numeric values is due to lucky circumstance that the requested numeric values start with 1 so that the "No" has the level index 1 and "Yes" the level index 2.